# Javascript date comparison not always working

Tags: javascript

My application is relying on a date comparison in order to take users "offline"

This is my code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    for (var s in _client) {
        if (_client.hasOwnProperty(s)) {
            var obj = _client[s];

            var lastVisit = new Date(_client[s].lastActive); // for example: 2013-10-8 9:52:24
            var thirtySecs = 31000;
            var now = new Date();
            var thirtySecsAgo = new Date(now - thirtySecs);


            if (lastVisit < thirtySecsAgo) {
                // Should now remove user
                // This does not always work for some reason
            }
        }
    }
}, 15000)
```

The logic is that it should check each active clients lastActive property (which is being updated by a heartbeat). But sometimes the `if` is not triggerd and therefore the user is not removed.

I have been unable to find why sometimes the user is not removed, even though more than 30 minutes have passed.

Any ideas what could be wrong and how i could make sure that old users are always removed?

Comment: Is there an error in your log? There might have been an exception raised from the Date construction.

Comment: Havent seen any exception. I added my complete `setInterval`

Comment: Do you mean 30 minutes or 30 seconds? You use 31000 which is 31 **seconds**, but you call it minutes..

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko I updated the code :) I mean 31 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Strange things sometimes happen with automatic cast. Try explicit conversion to timestamp values and use those.

```
var d = new Date();
var ts = d.valueOf();
// execute operations
```

Comment: I would convert all date objects as timestamps. This way it would be more safe to make comparison and errors could be easily spotted (in particular if Date(String) does the right job). So when you set lastVisit set a timestamp using date.valueOf(),  and then same with now. Then operate just with numbers.

Comment: Do you mean like this: `var d = new Date();
var lastVisit = d.valueOf("2013-10-8 9:52:24");` ?

Comment: No, I was suggesting the same as Oleksandr (next answer), just use valueOf() instead of getTime() (it's equivalent) and use the same function also before setting lastActive (code is not in the snippet) so that you do not have date as strings but just numbers.

Comment: What "strange things" are you implying? I can't see where the implicit cast would not work in the OPs script.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting variables **now**, **lastVisit** and **thirtySecs** to milliseconds via **getTime()**, so it will be easier to compare them as unsigned integers:

```
var lastVisit = (new Date(_client[s].lastActive)).getTime(); //1381215144000
var now = (new Date()).getTime(); //1381225150208    
var thirtySecs = 31*1000; //31000
var thirtySecsAgo = now - thirtySecs; //1381225119208
```